# Is using && to assign values and execute functions bad practice?

Tags: php

Take in example the following code

```
preg_match(
    $curlyBracesCapturer,
    $directory,
    $match
) && $directory != '' && isset($values[$match[1]]) && $directoryStack .= str_replace(
    $match[0],
    $placeholdersReplacements[$match[1]] . '/',
    $directory
);
```

I've seen thing's like this on frameworks, **when is it too much**?

Thanks!

Comment: For me it's too much but it's opinion-based question

Comment: What I do often is `if(($myObject = getSomeObject($myParam)) !== null) { // got an object }` but I never did string concatination before in an `if` statement. Theoretically you can put every statement inside an `if` construct. But as stated above it gets too much at some point and results in unreadable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something everybody has to decide for himself (or for the coding standards of his project).

In my opinion short things like `$var == 'test' && test();` are ok. 
But i would say that the example you provided is bad practice.

There is enough harddisk space, so such things aren't necessary.